# Adding Image after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

So I read this, what seems to be a very good article on the topic title:

http://www.rodsdot.com/javascript/Remote-Scripting-Images-(No-Need-For-AJAX).asp

What I don't understand is why it works?

I am fine with my work (monkey see, monkey do)but I figured why not ask.

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: "What I don't understand is why it works?" --- why shouldn't it work?

Comment: So why do the other examples fail?

Comment: because they are wrong :-S I still cannot get what **actually** confuses you

Comment: So onload triggers when the image has finished loading and then I add the image to the dom 
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_onLoad.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading all the images, css, scripts, etc.. on page load. This lets you load some images after the page load, letting the crucial part loads first.

It decrease the Page Load time, because it continue to load in the background after the Page Load was completed.

Comment: I think it works because when the element is created - the onload event fires and this means something to the browser in how the image is added to the screen that the other methods don't trigger?